# c# to query a json file

Tags: c#, json

I have a json file as such:

```
 {
  "rowId": "39",
  "refNumber": "19",
  "title": "Mobile",
  "date": "10/29/2015",
  "status": "saved"
 }{
  "rowId": "10",
  "refNumber": "478",
  "title": "Completion",
  "date": "10/30/2015",
  "status": "saved"
 }{
   "rowId": "11",
   "refNumber": "604",
   "title": "Online Order",
   "date": "10/30/2015",
   "status": "failed"
  }
```

What I'd like to do is query the json file in c# like as such with a winforms app:

```
string qrySaved = "select count(*) as total from file where status = 'saved'";
string qryFailed = "select count(*) as total from file where status = 'failed'";
```

Then place the results in two variables.

I did the following:

```
 logFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
 logFolder = logFolder.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "\\metrics");
 logFile = logFolder + @"\log.json";
```

I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json nuget resource and know how to read the first object but can't figure out how to query the file to return total counts based on a given element.

Comment: Looks a bit too broad - clarifying what is blocking you may help: read one/many files, get property from object, run LINQ/SQL query from string against an object (or maybe even something else).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("sample1.json");
        var array =  JArray.Parse(json);
        int savedcount = array.Count(i => i["status"].Value<string>() == "saved");
        int failedcount = array.Count(i => i["status"].Value<string>() == "failed");
    }
```

Might a typo but the JSON posted was invalid so I changed it as below to make it work:

```
[
    {
        "rowId": "39",
        "refNumber": "19",
        "title": "Mobile",
        "date": "10/29/2015",
        "status": "saved"
    },
    {
        "rowId": "10",
        "refNumber": "478",
        "title": "Completion",
        "date": "10/30/2015",
        "status": "saved"
    },
    {
        "rowId": "11",
        "refNumber": "604",
        "title": "Online Order",
        "date": "10/30/2015",
        "status": "failed"
    }
]
```

Comment: I found the JArray but am getting an error with - there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'key' of 'jtoken.value<t>(object)'

Comment: @will2m: Hmm that's weird. I tested in a console application and it compiled and worked fine. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json version 7.0.1

Comment: string json = logFile; //is the path to the file such as: c:\log.json

An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: yes - same version as well. the 2nd error is based on the savedcount.

Comment: Just replace "sample1.json" with your file path, don't assign the path to json variable. Also I think the first error is because your JSON is invalid. I fixed it but forgot to mention. I'll update my answer

Comment: @will2m: Updated the answer. I hope your actual JSON is valid otherwise I'd recommend to fix it first

Comment: I made it valid; but still get:  there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'key' of 'jtoken.value<t>(object)'  at the line: int savedcount = array.Count(i => i["status"].Value<string>() == "saved");
            int failedcount = array.Count(i => i["status"].Value<string>() == "failed");

Comment: @will2m: Sorry, I cannot reproduce that error. The sample code I posted works fine. Could you please update your question with the revised JSON and your relevant code?